# How can I add a border between each frame in a spritesheet?

Tags: c#

I'd like to figure out how I can add a 1 pixel border in between each frame that my spritesheet creator generates, can anyone help?

The function below takes an array of images and turns them into a table filled with bitmaps.

The program is supposed to take a gif and turn it into multiple spritesheets, so that it can be displayed in a game engine. That part is working fine, but I'd like to add a 1 pixel border in between each frame.

```
public Bitmap[] combineFrames(Image[] images, int columns)
        {
            int rows = columns;
            int imagesPerSheet = rows * columns;
            int sheets = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)images.Length / imagesPerSheet);
            Bitmap[] mapTable = new Bitmap[55]; //55 being the max #sheets 
            for (int x = 0; x < sheets; x++)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(images[0].Width * columns, images[0].Height * rows);

                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                int L = 0;
                int remainingNFrames = (images.Length - (imagesPerSheet * x));
                if (remainingNFrames < imagesPerSheet)
                {
                    L = remainingNFrames;
                }
                else
                {
                    L = imagesPerSheet;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i <= L; i++)
                {
                    int formulizedProduct = imagesPerSheet * (x) + (i);
                    if (formulizedProduct == images.Length) { break; } //should always be length - 1
                    Image image = images[formulizedProduct]; //16*x+i
                    int X = (image.Width * ((i - 1) % columns));
                    int Y = (image.Height * (int)((double)(i - 1) / columns));
                    graphics.DrawImage(
                      image,
                      X, //I feel like I'd have to adjust this part and the part below, but I'm not really sure.
                      Y
                    );
                }
                
                mapTable[x] = bitmap;
            }
            return mapTable;

        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can make a Rectangle 1 pixel larger than the reference Bitmap Frame, build an array of Rectangles with this same size, then draw your Bitmaps in a sequence inside these Rectangles at location `(1, 1)` instead of `(0, 0)` (the Rectangle in the sequence already gives you the coordinates inside the recipient (the larger, container, Bitmap). The larger Bitmaps should be sized base of the sum of these Rectangles: `(width * columns) + 1` and `(height * rows) + 1`.

Comment: don't do that, adding border will ruin your sprites